# After invoking ContextMenu, the click event bound to datatable TD does not work

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net) for listing rows. Recently, I implemented [ContextMenu](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin) plugin on datatable to enable user to right click on any row and select the context options such as editing row, deleting row and many more.

Following is the code used for implementing ContextMenu on DataTable:

```
$('#dtPOL').dataTable({
  "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    $(nRow).contextMenu({
        menu: 'cntxtmnuDataTable'
    },
    function (action, el, pos) {
        if (action != '') {
            alert('You selected: ' + action);
        }
        return true;
    });
  }
});
```

Along with this, I have also implemented the drill down functionality on DataTable as given and explained in [Drill-down rows](http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows), which works very well without any glitches. Following is the code:

```
$('#dtPOL tbody td').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

    if (i === -1) {
        $('img', this).attr('src', gImageURL + "b-qv-hide.png");
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnQuickView(oTable, nTr), 'quickView');
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push(nTr);
    }
    else {
        $('img', this).attr('src', gImageURL + "b-qv-show.png");
        $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp(function () {
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            anOpen.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

The function that is called in the above code snippet is as follows:

```
function fnQuickView(oTable, nTr) {
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut = '<div class="innerDetails">';
    sOut += '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Detailed Description:</td><td>:</td><td>' + aData[2] + '</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';
    sOut += '</div>';

    return sOut;
}
```

Now, the issue gets started once I invoke ContextMenu. As I have done it, the drill-down functionality stops working. On debugging, I found out that the click event on the TD.control does not fire at all, after the ContextMenu has been invoked.

Have tried searching on DataTable forum as well as Google but nothing helpful. Am sure, I am missing something. Request you to kindly help me as I have already spent more than 4 days and still no success. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I have even tried creating contextmenu on all the TDs in the row except for the 1st TD of each row, doubting that the contextmenu plugin might be conflicting with TD click event but no success.

Changed ... 
$(nRow).contextMenu
... to .... $('td:not(:eq(0))', nRow).contextMenu ... in the fnRowCallback API.

Comment: After lot of debugging, I found that the issue is not with DataTable but contextMenu. Now, since I was short of time, I have changed the contextmenu plugin and now I am using another context menu plugin from ... http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu ... which is built on the same plugin but with few enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is really with contextMenu Plugin....it unbinds all .click events over all the elements of webpage...so simply comment out all the statements of .js file which unbinds .click events on document...this trick worked for me...

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will keep that in mind but I have already implemented a better plugin. Thank you again.